# textures without color distortion through shading/lighting needed

Tags: three.js

I want to use a map/texture which isn't affected by lighting/shading. Which Three.js shader should I choose? In other 3D programs, you would probably use a map on the ambient color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MeshBasicMaterial`. It is not affected by lights.

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: texture } );
```

Comment: thats my problem, the colors defined in the bitmap image and rendered in three are not the same.
I want to use the image for color information, so why do I assign  color white and in a addition a map? I do not understand the logic behind that.

Comment: It is because the final color in `MeshBasicMaterial` is the diffuse `color` times the map color, component-wise. (The rgb values are remapped to 0-1 before multiplication.)

Comment: so is this a bug if the colors will not match?

Comment: It is unlikely there is a bug in the library related to this issue. Can you provide a simple live example to demonstrate the issue?